# React setState callback return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React and I was looking to achieve this kind of flow:

```
// set the state
// execute a function `f` (an async one, which returns a promise)
// set the state again
// return the promise value from the previous function
```

So, what I'm doing now is the following:

```
async function handleSomething() {
  this.setState((prevState) => { ... },
    () => {
      let result = await f()
      this.setState((prevState) => { ... },
        ...
      )
    })
  return result;
}
```

Hope you get the idea of what I want to achieve. Basically I want to get `result`, which is the value returned from `await`ing `f`, and return it in `handleSomething` so I can use it in another place, but wrapping it up inside those `setState` calls:

```
// g()
//   setState
//     res = f()
//       setState
//   return res
```

My question is, how can I do this properly? Maybe should I modify the state with the result value and get it from there?.

**EDIT:**

Usage of `handleSomething`:

```
// inside some async function
let result = await handleSomething()
```

Comment: Can you show use the usage of `handleSomething` too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a Promise that resolves once both `setState` calls are done:

```
function handleSomething() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        /*...*/
      },
      async () => {
        let result = await f();
        this.setState(
          prevState => {
            /*...*/
          },
          () => resolve(result)
          //    ^^^^^^^ resolve the promise with the final result
        );
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Which would be used like:

```
this.handleSomething().then(result => /* ... */)

// or

const result = await this.handleSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks! Using a promise is the way to go. Looks very neat :)