# Return from setState callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Parent component where I make a call to a function in my Child component using `refs`.

The Child component function has a `this.setState` and a callback function within the `this.setState`.

```
handleSaveProject = async () => {
    this.setState({
            //set some state
        }, () => {
            if(this.state.isValid){
                let project = this.initializeProject();
                return ProjectAPI.saveProject(project).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response); //ok
                    return response;
                });
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This works fine. Now, from the Parent component I make call using the refs.

```
 handleSaveClick = () => {
        if(createProjectComponentRef.current){
            createProjectComponentRef.current.handleSaveProject().then((saveResponse) => {
                console.log(saveResponse); //undefined
                if(saveResponse && saveResponse.status === 200){
                    this.handleDialog();
                    ProjectAPI.getProjects().then((response) => {
                        this.setState({projects: response})
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I am able to call the Child component function but the response (return value) I get within the Parent component is undefined. Any help with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleSaveProject` does not actually return anything, and I don't think `setState` returns anything either.

You need to do something like the answer here: [React setState callback return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273673/react-setstate-callback-return-value)

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
   this.setState({
        //set some state
    }, () => {
        if(this.state.isValid){
            let project = this.initializeProject();
            return ProjectAPI.saveProject(project).then((response) => {
                console.log(response); //ok
                resolve(response);
            });
          }
     }
   );
)};
```